# Looking for the source of a Hadith by Ibn Majjah about a son and his father?

Tags: source-identification

I read a `hadith` that goes something like:

> There was a young man who came to the Prophet Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim
>   complaining to the messenger Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim saying: “My
>   father takes my money, he always asks for my money” Rasool Allah
>   Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim said: “Well call your father”. As he went, the
>   angel Jibraeel came down at that moment and he said: “Rasool Allah,
>   when the father comes to you ask him, What was you saying in secret
>   when you was coming here, the father was muttering something the son
>   couldn’t here, so ask him what he was saying. When the father arrived
>   Rasool Allah Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim asked “is it true what your son
>   is saying?” the man replied saying “Oh messenger, if you only knew
>   what I was using his money for anyway Im using it to look after his
>   poor Aunty, she has nobody to look after her, were else am I going to
>   place his money, in places only that I have to” So the prophet
>   Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim said “I want to ask you a question, tell me
>   what you saying in secret when you was on your way here” The father
>   looked at the Messenger Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim and said “I made some
>   verses of poetry” to which Rasool Allah Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim said “
>   please say them to me” So he said “ Oh son I nourished you when you
>   was a baby  And I looked after you in care as you grew up until you
>   became an adolescent  You lived upon what I worked for and strived and
>   sacrificed in my body and time and wealth, So that you may live
>   healthy Whenever a night passed you when you was sick or ill or
>   coughed I was the first to be up, carrying you and looking upon you
>   with my heart Afraid if a little atom or a little breeze would harm
>   you in anyway I could not sleep whilst seeing you sick until you slept
>   and then I slept When I used to see you sick, it was as if I was the
>   one who was sick or ill And so my eyes would always overwhelm with
>   tears but you never knew And then he said, and when you finally
>   reached adulthood which all my life I was anticipating And looking
>   forward to seeing you become that Until you reached the day when I
>   have all my life anticipated in my heart to see you reach and rejoice,
>   My son you gave me a REWARD, And your reward was……………………. HARSHNESS! 
>   And frowniness and mistreatment, As if I am the one who owes you and
>   you owe me nothing The way you treated me was like a neighbour would
>   treat his neighbour I wish that you even gave me that” Rasool Allah
>   Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim then looked at the father and the father
>   looked at him, and the Prophet Salalahu Alayhi Wasalim beard was
>   soaked with tears. From his emotions, Rasool Allah Salalahu Alayhi
>   Wasalim grabbed the boy from his chest, shook him and said to him “
>   you and everything you own belong to your father”

I am trying to find the source, and it said to be from `Ibn Majah`, but I cannot find it. Can someone please explain where it is from?

Answer (score 2):

This Hadith has been narrated in a [number of ways](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/hadithsearch.php).  It is narrated in Ibn Majah but not as you have mentioned it in your question.  You can see the narration in Ibn Majah [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/1323800)

Comment: The first link doesn't show the correct hadith.

Comment: What about the rest of the story?

Comment: TH answer from Masjid Al-Birr Wat-Taqwa below is the right one. this is not

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you will find this version in Ibn Majah, but in Tafsir Qurtubi instead:  https://syedfawaz2002.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/the-pain-of-a-troubled-father-a-remarkable-hadith/ Qurtubi

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate your answer, as is it looks like a link only answer, which might be accepted because of the kind of question

Answer (score 1):

Well the common and well reported statement from this hadith, which you may find in some hadith collections is the last part

> "you and everything you own belong to your father"
>
> أَنْتَ وَمَالُكَ لأَبِيكَ

See for example in Sunan ibn Majah [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/1323800) and [here](http://sunnah.com/urn/1266100), and in [Sunan abu Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/24/115). This is the part of the hadith which is qualified hasan or sahih. You can find this version also in also in [al-Kabri المعجم الكبير](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=84&bookhad=9838) of at-Tabarani and [mu'jam a-Zawaid مجمع الزاوئد ومنبع الفوائد](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=6777&idto=6787&bk_no=87&ID=1362) of al-Haythamy who indicates that it's also in sahih ibn Hibban ... and thatit was considered da'if by Imam Ahmad.

I could also find a longer Version which may be similar to your quotation is inidicated in tafsir al-Qutubi, but it was taken from [al-Awsat المعجم الأوسط](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=475&pid=280701&hid=6744) of Imam at-Tabarni (The narration chain contains some unknown and only acceptable rawys) and an other is in [as-Saghir المعجم الصغير](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=86&bookhad=908) of Imam at-Tabarani, but the last one includes some poem the father said and therefore wouldn't fit to your quotation. But as you see only the last part is accepted, while the longer narrations are very doubtful!

**Conclusion** 
The information that this hadith is in Sunan ibn Majah is wrong when it comes to the exact or long wording, but -only- the quintessence is a part of two narrations in Sunan ibn Majah which you may find in the above links.

And Allah knows best!