# Father's share in daughter's salary

Tags: money, parents, children

Does a father has 1/3rd Share in her daughter's salary or pension? Is this listed in the Shariah?

Answer (score 1):

A father has a general right to take from the property of his children.

> أنت ومالك لوالدك، إن أولادكم من أطيب كسبكم، فكلوا من كسب أولادكم
>
> You and your wealth belong to your father. Your children are among the best of your earnings, so eat from the earning of your children.
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2292) and [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3530)</sup>

Also see: [Looking for the source of a Hadith by Ibn Majjah about a son and his father?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16695/) for context.

There is no limit (such as a third) but the following conditions apply:

- taking it must not cause harm to the child
- he must not take something which the child needs
- he must not take something from one child to give it to another
- he must be in need - the Hanbalis do not consider this to be necessary

---

**Ref:**

> ولأب أن يأخذ من مال ولده ما شاء، ويتملكه، مع حاجة الأب إلى ما يأخذه، ومع عدمها، صغيرا كان الولد أو كبيرا، بشرطين أحدهما أن لا يجحف بالابن، ولا يضر به، ولا يأخذ شيئا تعلقت به حاجته. الثاني أن لا يأخذ من مال ولده فيعطيه الآخر  نص عليه أحمد ... وقال أبو حنيفة، ومالك، والشافعي: ليس له أن يأخذ من مال ولده إلا بقدر حاجته
>
> A father can take whatever he wishes from the  property of his child, and can become its owner, be it because of the father's need or without it, whether the child is a minor or adult, with two conditions: One is that he should not be unjust to the son, harm him, or take anything that he needs himself. The second is that he should not take from his son's wealth and give it to another. This was stated by (Imam) Ahmad ... And (Imams) Abu Hanifa, Malik and Shafi'i said: The father may not take from his son's wealth except to the extent of his need.
>
> <sup>— [Mughni](https://shamela.ws/book/8463/2383#p1) - Ibn Qudaymah</sup>

> Children (awlaad) is a general term which includes both males and females. The father has the right to dispose of his children’s wealth
>
> [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12214/)

Comment: Just to be clear, this also applies if the child is *baligh* and living independently with their own family? Regardless of gender?

Comment: @goldPseudo I have added references which should clarify this.